# How to use `allow` with `let` in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this code in RSpec.

```
before(:each) do
  @company = Company.create(price: 700)
  allow(@company).to receive(:foo){5}
end
```

Can I use `allow` method in a `let` also?
If yes how can I use it?

Comment: First question: **What have you tried?**

Comment: `let(:company){ Company.create(price: 700) }` and I have no idea where should I put `allow` and how to get created company instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about

```
let(:company) do
  company = Company.create!(price: 700)
  allow(company).to receive(:foo){5}
  company
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add using tap which is a much better approach:

```
let(:company) do
  Company.create!(price: 700)
    .tap do |c|
      allow(c).to receive(:foo){5}
    end
end
```